# How to find condition when sum is specific value by MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'd like to know some condition from this table.

```
date value
2022-01-01 5
2022-01-02 1
2022-01-03 3
2022-01-04 0
2022-01-05 2
2022-01-06 2
```

When is the date if sum of values exceed 10?
Actually, the answer is '2022-01-05'. Because sum from '2022-01-01' to '2022-01-05' is 11. It's easy for us as a human.
But how do I express in MySQL? Please let me know.

Comment: What have you already tried? The answer is also `2022-01-06`, since value exceeds 10 on this date, too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using MySQL 8+ then window functions makes your requirement easy:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, SUM(value) OVER (ORDER BY date) sum_value
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT date
FROM cte
WHERE sum_value > 10
ORDER BY date
LIMIT 1;
```

On earlier versions of MySQL we can express the rolling sum with a correlated subquery:

```sql
SELECT date
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE (SELECT SUM(t2.value)
       FROM yourTable t2
       WHERE t2.date <= t1.date) >= 10
ORDER BY date
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. Unfortunately, I use MySQL 5.7. What should I do?

Comment: I have added an option for earlier versions of MySQL.

Comment: I see. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach for MySQL < 8, using a user variable to store the rolling sum -

```sql
SELECT `date`
FROM (
    SELECT t.*, @sum_value := @sum_value + `value` AS `sum_value`
    FROM t, (SELECT @sum_value := 0) z
    ORDER BY `date` ASC
) y
WHERE `sum_value` >= 10
ORDER BY `date` ASC
LIMIT 1;
```